# Configuring nginx to add a forward proxy?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy

So I have an app that spins up a web service at http://localhost:4206.

I have copied the app to an EC2 instance, and now want to start the service, but allow everyone (external consumers) to hit the service. I know that I can configure nginx to add a forward proxy from port 8080 (external) to my server's port (4206).

I've found the following guide: https://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server

However, I'm unsure of what exactly on this guide I should be doing...

What should this snippet look like for me?

```
server {
    listen       8080;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

Some direction would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am unsure if this would really help so I will post this as a comment. I did actually configure nginx before to proxy a node server running in the same ec2 instance together with a php fpm on it. And the configuration i have is this https://gist.github.com/nosweat/a1e991c9359b719459e1#file-php-node-nginx-conf-L34

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    # Port
    listen       8080;

    # Set the name of the virtual server
    server_name  _;

    # Proxy pass everything to http://localhost:4206/
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4206;
        # Set the proxied host
        proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    }
}
```

Read more on proxy_pass and other directives here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this is giving me a `! java.net.BindException: Address already in use` when I try to start the service on my EC2 instance. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to check which process is using the port - try `netstat -pant`

Comment: Gotcha -- so killed the process, and now tried curling the dev box, getting a 403 forbidden nginx error.  If I start the service on my dev box and curl localhost:4206 without the nginx forward proxy, I do not get this 403 forbidden. Is there anything you can think of that would cause this?

Comment: Check the host being proxied to the localhost:4206 is what localhost:4206 is expecting. I guess it is expecting "localhost", if so, add the following  `proxy_set_header    Host localhost` after the `proxy_pass` line.

Comment: Nothing, unfortunately -- restarted nginx, and still the 403. Would there be anything else? Sorry, I'm extremely unfamiliar with this...

Comment: Check both servers' log?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95745/discussion-between-ryan-yu-and-tan-hong-tat).